# In Dart get next occurring date from an rrule

Tags: dart, rrule

Is there a Dart library or, lacking one, a correct way to handle finding the next date that would be returned from a correctly formatted rrule?

For example give the following rule:
"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE;INTERVAL=1;DTSTART=20180328T160000Z"

I would want a date time value of the next occurring Wed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there is a library for this, but I quickly came up with this. Not complete, but it's a start.

```
void main() {
    var today = DateTime.parse('20180328T160000Z');

    var days = today.weekday < DateTime.wednesday ? DateTime.wednesday - today.weekday : 7 - today.weekday + DateTime.wednesday;

    var next = today.add(new Duration(days:days));
    print(next);
}
```

Others might come up with something better. Parsing the rule would be the hard part.

Comment: Its seems like there is already a library for parsing RRULEs https://pub.dev/packages/grec_minimal

The real hard part is generating the recurring dates.

Comment: Well that's not all that hard, you just need to know how far in the future you want to generate these dates for

Comment: There is now a package for this https://pub.dev/packages/rrule

Comment: That's awesome news.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [rrule](https://pub.dev/packages/rrule) for a while and quite happy with it